# Symfony: How to change a form field attribute in an action?

Tags: forms, checkbox, symfony1, action

I've got a functioning form with a sfWidgetFormChoice that acts as a list of checkboxes. I'm able to set the checkboxes to "ticked" by default with the following:

```
'status' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => array(1, 2, 3), 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true), array('checked' => 'checked'))
```

... where the checkboxes are called "status" and the possible values are 1/2/3.

However, because of something else, instead of ticking them all by default I'd like to be able to control the "checked" status from an action. How do I do this? I've tried everything logical I can think of but I just can't figure out the right syntax.

Basically, I'm looking for something like:

```
$this->form->getWidget('status')->setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it not work or what is your problem? Because your syntax seems valid. Any error messages?

Comment: Uhhh... that's crazy. It DOES work! Well, thanks for making me trying it again, must have been something cached in my browser.

Comment: If you want to add an "answer" I can mark it as accepted for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax seems valid according to the [sfForm](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm#method_getwidget)  and [sfWidget](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidget#method_setattribute) API documentation.