# symfony setting value of specific checkbox widgets in form

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a widget defined with a series of checkboxes that is essentially used to build up a bit flag. So I have a DB column 'access_bits', and I have several checkboxes generated on in the form class, in the format of 'access_bits[]', with the appropriate values (i.e. 1,2,16,1024 etc)

following the solution on this post ([Symfony: How to change a form field attribute in an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254620/symfony-how-to-change-a-form-field-attribute-in-an-action)) - which is simple and sensible - I am able to magically set the attribute for **all** the checkboxes. But how can I target specific ones (preferably by value)?

**TO CLARIFY:**

HTML:

```
<input name="user[access_bit][]" value="1" /> Level 1
<input name="user[access_bit][]" value="2" /> Level 2
<input name="user[access_bit][]" value="4" /> Level 3
<input name="user[access_bit][]" value="8" /> Level 4
```

In the DB I have a column that has a bitwise integer. So for example, to have Level 1 and Level 2 checked, the value in the column would be 3. To have them all checked, the value would be 15.

"What I Want" PHP in action.class.php

```
$exampleValue = 4;
foreach ($form->getWidget('access_bit') as $thisWidget)
{
    if ($thisWidget->getValue() == $exampleValue)
    {
        $thisWidget->setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
}
```

... which would cunningly set the checkbox next to Level 3 as ticked.

I do not want to use jQuery to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this....on your form save you can use this

```
 $samplevar =  $this->your_form->save();
 $samplevar->setYOURFORMFIELDNAME(array of values(1,2,3)); 
 $this->sample = YOURFORM($samplevar);
```

or,

on showing the form in first you can also pass the value in form while setting

```
 $this->samplevariable = YOURFORM($this->getYOURMODEL->setYOURFORMFIELDNAME(array of values(1,2,3) which u get form db getYOURFORMFIELDNAME);
```

if you have values in comma seperated you cane use explode directly

```
 $samplevar =  $this->YOURFORMNAME->save();
 $samplevar->setYOURFORMFIELDNAME(explode(',', $samplevar ->getYOURFORMFIELDNAME())); 
 $this->YOURFORMNAME  = new YOURFORMForm($samplevar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setDefault method :

```
$thisWidget->setDefault(array($examplevalue));
```